# Angularjs ng-disabled not working with autofill

Tags: angularjs

When I reload the browser and show login page. Two input field for username and password are autofill with chrome.
But the login button is greyout and show "not allowed" cursor when hover on.
If I click anywhere in the page, the login button will be enable.
Here is my code for login form:

```
<form name="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" id="login-email" class="form-control"
               name="email"
               ng-model="vm.data.email"
               required
               placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" id="login-password" class="form-control"
               name="password"
               ng-model="vm.data.password"
               required
               placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-rectangle btn-primary"
                ng-click="vm.submit()"
                ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Sign in
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You may want to follow [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1460). It was an issue with AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You may try autocomplete false.

```
<form name="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" id="login-email" class="form-control"
           name="email"
           ng-model="vm.data.email"
           required
           placeholder="Email Address" autocomplete="false">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" id="login-password" class="form-control"
           name="password"
           ng-model="vm.data.password"
           required
           placeholder="Password" autocomplete="false">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-rectangle btn-primary"
            ng-click="vm.submit()"
            ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Sign in
    </button>
</div>
```